# Error: Unknown provider: PopupProvider <- Popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

> how to resovle the error when I use the angular-popup.js Plug-ins?
>    as the following error log
>
> the  angularjs code as the following

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-popups']);
app.config(function (PopupProvider) {
    PopupProvider.title = '提示';
    PopupProvider.okValue = '确定';
    PopupProvider.cancelValue = '取消';
});
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, Popup) {}}
```

> the html code as the following

```
   <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="add()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

the error log info

```
Error: Unknown provider: PopupProvider <- Popup
```

Comment: Please make sure you have included the js file in your index.html file

Comment: ...and that the module as actually called `angular-popups`.

Comment: I had inclued  the js!  

Like this :
  <script src="/assets/dist/angular-popups.js"></script>

Comment: why popup , there are so many good libraries out there

Comment: @Sajeetharan
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/dashboard.css">
    <script src="/assets/js/lib/base64.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/lib/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/lib/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/dist/angular-popups.js"></script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your angular.js reference version could be the issue. Update the version to above 1.3. Add the reference for angularjs and then add the reference for angular-popup.js as follows,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/angular-popups.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had Used the <script src="/assets/js/lib/angular-1.0.1.min.js">.

You mean I have to include another js called "angular.min.js"?

Comment: After I had updated the version to 1.4.5, It shows the error log  

    angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=gateway&p1=Error%3A…%2F%2F172.16.192.90%3A8080%2Fassets%2Fjs%2Flib%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:38
    at n (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:37)
    at eb (angular.min.js:40)
    at d (angular.min.js:19)
    at yc (angular.min.js:20)
    at Zd (angular.min.js:19)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:292)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Can we talk in chatroom and to be quick location the problem?
by the way how to post the file to show your code

Comment: yeah , I should include another model like this.
var app = angular.module('gateway', ["status",'angular-popups']);
otherwise,It would print the error. @Sajeetharan

Comment: sure @Sajeetharan